# insert page number add labels to images and tables

Tags: libreoffice

In libre office writer I want to insert:
page number in which the first five pages have latin numbers (i ii iii iv v) and after the fifth page have numbers.
Also I have tables and images in which I want to insert label like

```
image 1: text for image 1 
image 2: text for image 2
table 1: text for table 1
```

How can I make it?

Answer (score 0):

Define your own page style (`F11`) and check footer (or header: where you want the page numbering go to) to on.

Then `Insert>Fields>More Fields...>Document>Type: Page>Format: Roman` in the appropriate section.

Do the same (new page style) for a second custom style.

At the end of page 5 `Insert>Manual Break>Type: Page Break` and apply your second style. Then edit the footer accordingly.

For images: select image, right click and choose `Insert caption`

For tables: `Tools>Options...>LO Writer>AutoCaption` check `LO Writer Texttable` before inserting a table.

If you already made the table(s) I'm afraid you have to place the cursor just below a table and insert a new table to get the caption (delete unwanted rows after the operation).

Does this help?